# Python3 Socket Programming

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a software in Python3 and I need to Communicate with Whole World.
How I can create a socket over the wide area network instead of local area network!

Or Does socket programming works in such a way that client is in another network???

Plz I Need Answer as soon as possible!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example

```
import socket

HOSTNAME = "the host name"
PORT = xxxx

my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
my_socket.connect((HOST, PORT))
```

And I suggest you reed the [Documentaion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) for waht you need.